# Can't Access ActiveMQ Web Console

Tags: eclipse, browser, console, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

I am having trouble accessing ActiveMQ's web console.

On [their website](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html) it says you can access the console through the URL : localhost:8161/admin

But all I get when I try this is "This webpage is not available"

I found another site saying I can access it through port '61616', which gives me a response in the form of the following : 
[image]

I have done some extensive searching on this issue, and have found others with the same problem, but have not come across a solution.

I am fairly new to using ActiveMQ so please excuse me if I have left out any relevant information.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is your activemq up and running?

Comment: Yes it is running. I also see some error messages showing up on my console in eclipse when I hit the above URL. I do not have access to my machine at the moment, but I will update with more info as soon as I can.

Comment: Running in Eclipse you say? Are you running embedded or full distribution? The console is only available if you start activemq with the jetty configuration enabled and the admin console deployed. It's by default activemq.xml configuration.

Comment: Embedded. Although I am using Tomcat, not jetty. What exactly do you mean by having the admin console deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The admin console is a web application ([WAR-file](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/activemq/activemq-web-console/5.12.1/activemq-web-console-5.12.1.war)) deployed in an embedded Jetty server that starts up along with ActiveMQ standalone distribution.

Since you intend to run ActiveMQ inside a web application inside Tomcat, it would not make sense to fire up a jetty server.

Simply deploy the web console WAR to your Tomcat. You need to point out the JMS/OpenWire connection URI as well as JMX connection URI to ActiveMQ Web Console to get it going. Typically in Tomcat setenv.sh (or similar file):

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dwebconsole.type=properties -Dwebconsole.jms.url=tcp://localhost:61616- Dwebconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi -Dwebconsole.jmx.user=admin -Dwebconsole.jmx.password=mypassw0rd"
```

This requires you to have JMX setup on your Tomcat instance. If not, [check this Tomcat doc page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html) out.

This will deploy the console just like any app in your Tomcat (not port 8161).

Off-topic, but a nice feature with decoupling the web console from the actual broker is that you can access a the activem broker of a master/slave pair using failover protocol and comma separated jmx settings.

Comment: Cool, I will give this a go tomorrow

Comment: It works! I already had JMX set up so I just needed to deploy the WAR and add the extra console arguments to my server startup. Thank you for your help!